# After enabling the hardware virtualization in BIOS, Windows 8 fails to load

Tags: windows-8, intel-core-i5, vt-x

After enabling the hardware virtualization in BIOS, Windows 8 fails to load. When I switched off the HV, everything is alright.

What's the problem and how to resolve it?

(HP Pavilion Sleekbook 15-b055sr),

Comment: The problem was solved by BIOS update.

Comment: No. It doesn't. Now I can boot the laptop with enabled virualization in the bios. But if I also added Hyper-V services in Windows, everything is bad again.